# How do I remove HTML elements beforePageLoad on an XPage

Tags: html, xpages, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I have an XPage which can be used for editing or just reading based on an user's role. Now I need to implement this feature. The solution is really simple - just remove adding, editing, and other HTML elements. The problem is that I only can execute SSJS code, but not CSJS on a page loading. When I tried to do it like this `document.` in SSJS it gives me a predictable exception - `document` is not recongized. How do I execute it on page load anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to remove HTML elements from rendered page.

Use the property **"rendered"** instead to determine which controls should be rendered depending on user rights. ("Rendered" means created and sent to browser.)

You can set this property here

[image]

or here

[image]

Insert SSJS code there which should return true (= visible) or false (= invisible).

Comment: Yep, this solution looks like much smater, thank you!

Comment: Here's the question about 'visibility'. Does it only hide or in other words makes dislpay:none, or doesn't include the element at all? Cause I need it to be absolutely absent on a page

Comment: It's the latter. Not rendered elements aren't at the page at all.

Answer (score 4):

The order of page loading is (XPages events are in bold):

- a server-side map of all components on the XPage and associated custom controls are loaded into memory
- **beforePageLoad**: developer's server-side code runs against those components
- the server-side components are iterated and updated based on computations or bindings to backend documents
- **afterPageLoad**: developer's server side code runs against those components
- **beforeRenderResponse**: developer's server-side code runs against those components (using this event means it's also processed during any partial refreshes)
- render response iterates the components and works out the HTML to pass to the browser
- **afterRenderResponse**: developer's server-side code runs against the components

As you can see, SSJS runs only against the server-side map of components, not against the client-side DOM. If you want to amend that, you can use onClientLoad but I don't think that runs after a partial refresh. So your amendments to the DOM may get lost after a partial refresh (you'll need to check). If you want changes to DOM elements to persist, there are two options:

1. Use `dojo.behavior`. jQuery may have a corresponding call that could be used.
2. Write a renderer in Java to change the HTML outputted for a specific type of component.

It sounds like you're strengths are in the client-side, so the former may be the best option.

Comment: This is a very neat and succinct summary of the page loading events. It should be in the next edition of any XPages book!